# Why two different characters have the same ASCII value?

Tags: php, character-encoding, char, character, ascii

Not sure what's happening here, but if I use the Php function ord(), which returns the ASCII value of a character, I obtain the same value for two distinct characters.

```
print ord("’");
```

outputs 226

```
print ord("—");
```

outputs 226, too.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think those are ASCII characters. They are unicode characters and ord doesn't work with unicode.

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit character set with 128 characters. ASCII has no character 226. What you're seeing is ord() being confused by unexpected input, and PHP being unhelpful in general. None of those characters are number 226 in any encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are both not ASCII values. `ord` only turns a single byte into a decimal number, it is not actually "character aware". Both of those characters are multibyte UTF-8 characters starting with the same byte, `226`. `ord` ignores the following bytes.

Comment: The documentation for [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) does support what's stated in the question. That seems a bit confusing.

Comment: PHP can be pretty darn inaccurate when it comes to talking about strings and characters. Fact is you can feed any random *byte* from `00` through `FF` into `ord` and it will spit out a number in the range 0 to 255. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @bzlm, `ord("’")` cannot possibly return the ASCII value of its argument, since here the argument is not an ASCII character.